# const i = new Image(); does not work on react-native iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, reactjs, expo, react-native

I am having the following error in react-native:

```sh
[Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Image]
* src/utils/b64ToBlob.js:45:56 in Promise$argument_0
```

And this is the function where it fail in `b64ToBlog.js`:

```js
export const getImageDimensions = (file) => new Promise((resolved) => {
  const i = new Image();
  i.onload = () => resolved(i);
  i.src = file;
});
```

On both `iOS` and `Android`, it fails on `const i = new Image();`:

How can I provide `Image` or get an image dimensions from an URL or how can I provide `Image` in react-native?

**Edit**

For those interested, this is my final solution:

```js
import { Platform, Image as ImageNative } from 'react-native';

export const getImageDimensions = (file) => new Promise((resolved) => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'web') {
    const i = new Image();
    i.onload = () => resolved(i);
    i.src = file;
    return i;
  } else {
    return getSizeNative(file).then(resolved);
  }
});

function getSizeNative(uri) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ImageNative.getSize(uri, (width, height) => resolve({ width, height }), reject)
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've shown is for the DOM [`Image` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/Image), not React Native's [`Image` component](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image).

Looking at the API for it, it looks like React Native's `Image` component provides a [`getSize` static method](https://reactnative.dev/docs/image#getsize):

```
import { Image } from "react-native";

export const getImageDimensions = (file) => new Promise((resolved, reject) => {
    Image.getSize(
        file,
        (width, height) => resolve({width, height}),
        reject
    );
});
```

Sadly the documentation doesn't seem to say how the size is reported to the success function<s>, so you may have to dig deeper or try it and see what you get.</s> ...but from the code subsequently posted in the question, it looks like it receives them as discrete parameters, so I've updated the above.